# Post an image in a comment on Facebook

Tags: facebook, comments

Is there a way to post a photo when I leave a comment in Facebook?

I want to be able to include an inline image when I comment.

Or is this not enabled/allowed?

Comment: it won't be allowed.

Comment: i hope if there is some way to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Facebook does not have such a feature yet. You can only attach images to your "notes" and "messages". Your only chance is to paste the link to the image as a text in your comment.